# Where should I store image as ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension where users can set images from their computer as their background. So far, I am able to have the image stored as an ArrayBuffer in `chrome.storage.local` but only to a max of 5MB. This limits what photos my users can upload.

In this case, is there anywhere else I could possibly store the image or could I read the images from disk?

Here is how I am reading files from a users device

```js
  async handleFile() {
      const options = {
        types: [
          {
            description: "Image",
            accept: {
              "image/*": [".jpg"],
            },
          },
        ],
      };
      let [fileHandle] = await window.showOpenFilePicker(options);
      const file = await fileHandle.getFile(); // once a user picks an image return the path of that image
      //  Lets let the user do the reader on the load
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener(
        "load",
        function () {
          chrome.storage.sync.set({ background: false }, () => {
            console.log(reader.result);
            chrome.storage.local.set({ image: reader.result }, () => {
              chrome.tabs.query(
                { active: true, currentWindow: true },
                (tabs) => {
                  chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[0].id);
                }
              );
            });
          });
        },
        false
      );
      console.log(file);
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      // if (file.size < 5000000) {
      //   this.error = "";
      // } else {
      //   this.error = "File Size is too large";
      // }
    },
```

Comment: chrome.storage.local is not actually limited to 5MB even if you don't add `unlimitedStorage` permission. That said, you should use `IndexedDB` because it allows storing ArrayBuffer directly.

Comment: Are you sure? When I upload a photo beyond 5MB, I get the error `Unchecked runtime.lastError: QUOTA_BYTES quota exceeded`. For reference I will post the code that I am using. Regardless, I will attempt your IndexedDB solution. Thank you!

Comment: One item is indeed limited to 5MB in chrome.storage.local.